# AD7173-8 gain register default value

Tags: adc, delta

In the AD7173-8 ADC, 
the default gain value is said to depend on the IC type. In the datasheet, the value is mentioned as 0x5XXXX0. But I couldn't find the exact value in the datasheet anywhere.

should I consider it as 0x5FFFF0 or?
I am a newbie to the circuitry. Sorry if this is a noob question.
Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each chip is factory calibrated so each chip will have different value so it cannot be printed on datasheet.

Comment: Sorry for this noob question.Is there anyway we can determine the value ? Like reading a register ?

Comment: It is a read/write register.